# AngularJs Service Strophe.js receive message in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmpp, message, strophe

I have a basic XMPP javascript client working on Strophe.js.
I am trying to "convert" it into AngularJS project.

I have created Angular Service for creating Strophe connection to XMPP server.
I have added handler onMessage and onPresence for retrieving messages from Strophe connection in Service.

How can I get the onMessage and onPresence callback function in Controller to display message in the view.

Comment: I have written AngularJs Service XMPPService
`code`
function auth(login, password) {
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://localhost:7070/http-bind/';
xmppConnection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
xmppConnection.connect(login, password, onConnect);
}

Comment: function onConnect(status)
{if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
xmppConnection.addHandler(onMessage, null, 'message', null, null,  null);
xmppConnection.addHandler(onPresence, null, 'presence');
}
}
function onMessage(message){
console.log('service message = '+message);
return true;
};
function onPresence(message){
console.log('service  onPresence message = '+message);
return true;
};

Comment: Please, edit your question adding your code properly formatted (see help). The code you showed in your comments doesn't appear to be an Angular Service...